# how to write best for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Expense table stores the daily expenses reported by the employees for reimbursement to the Accounts department. Please list all the Employee Ids whose Total Monthly expense for a given month is greater than the Average Monthly expense of their Department for that month.Here are the scripts to Create table and insert sample rows, just to give you an idea of the data would look like in the database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Expense (Department_Id varchar(20), Employee_Id varchar(20), Expense_Date date, Expense_Amt decimal(18,0))INSERT INTO Expense VALUES ('D1', 'E1', '2019-08-02',100), ('D1', 'E1', '2019-08-05',150), ('D1', 'E1', '2019-08-02',200), ('D1', 'E2', '2019-08-12',900), ('D1', 'E2', '2019-08-15',1000), ('D2', 'E3', '2019-08-15',500), ('D2', 'E4', '2019-08-20',550), ('D2', 'E5', '2019-08-10',400), ('D2', 'E6', '2019-09-10',600), ('D3', 'E7', '2019-08-14',700)
```

Comment: Put your attempt(s) in the question, using the [edit] feature, not in the comment. Also, ***please*** learn what a line break and white space are; not just in your code but in any of your written language. In order for a*any* text to be easily read, it needs to be well presented.

Comment: What is your question here though, you don't ask anything just give us a problem. *Is this homework?* What have ***you*** tried to solve the problem? Why didn't it work? What are you asking? [so] isn't a free coding site. You've read the [tour], so you should know that. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you to read "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With that, some user could help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can get this by below SQL-

```
select Employee_Id,SUM(Expense_Amt) as Total_expense,AVG(temp.d_ex) department_avg_exp from expense 
left outer join (
select AVG(Expense_Amt) d_ex,MONTH(Expense_Date)month_id ,Department_Id from Expense group by Department_Id, MONTH(Expense_Date)
) temp ON temp.Department_Id = Expense.Department_Id

GROUP BY Employee_Id,MONTH(Expense_Date)
HAVING AVG(temp.d_ex) <SUM(Expense_Amt)
```